# Match exact word and remove leading space in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression.

Requirement:

I need to select a complete word from a string (word might contain special character or anything). And m pretty close to the solution.

Example:

```
character-set
Regular expression: (?:^|\s)(cent-er)(?=\s|$)
Result: " character-set" with a leading space.
```

But i want to remove leading space from the selected word. The word should match exactly i.e if i say character or character- or -set or set it should not get any result.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. You must deal with capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you seem to describe (as far as I could understand, that is), but maybe what you are looking for are **[word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**: `\b`. Try the regex (parentheses optional):

```
(\b)(cent-er)(\b)
```

Other than that, if you *have to have* a space before the word, then you will have to match it (and then use capturing groups to extract the word without the space), because JavaScript's regex has no lookbehinds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need exactly this but if I give "er" or "-er" then "er " "-er" in "cent-er" got select from the word. I do'not want like this. Thanks in advance once again.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the JS code you are using for that?